# formal definition for "data type with larger range"

Tags: programming-languages, definitions

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_(computer_programming)#Range_of_a_variable) defines `range of data type`:

> *the set of possible values that that variable can hold.*

Suppose we have two data types *A* and *B*. Now, with attention to
the definition of *widening* in section `7.4` of [Concepts of Programming Languages](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134997182), we
can say:

> *range of B is larger than A* when *range of B* includes at least
>     approximations of all members of *range of A*.

But above definition is informal; because "accuracy" of approximation is not
determined. For example we can consider `0` as approximate for
`0` of `int` and `1` as approximate for
all other members of `int`. So we give a strange statement:

`range of int ≤ range of {0,1}`

Although we can add the `|A| ≤ |B|` as a criteria to avoid
some strange statements like above one (`|A|` means [Cardinal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number) for set `A`); but the problem of "accuracy" remains again.

Do you know a formal definition for "a data type with larger range"?

Comment: $1$ being an approximation for all nonzero integers is pretty abusive, though they say that some tribes count with "one, two, many".

Comment: Why do you feel the need for a formal definition ?

Comment: You're placing too much faith in Wikipedia, and in any case you are trying to define formally a phrase that has several possible meanings, of which Wikipedia lists two (range of a numeric type, range of an array). If you seek more formal and more exact understanding, the first step is to not read Wikipedia and open a textbook. We can suggest one if you tell us what you're after in the grander scheme of things.

Answer (score 1):

$$B_{\text{min}}\le A_{\text{min}}\land B_{\text{max}}\ge A_{\text{max}}$$

should do (with the implicit assumption that the types $A$ and $B$ are appropriate to represent numbers).

Comment: You're assuming that the datatypes in question are linearly ordered and that an inclusion of $A$ into $B$ is understood.

Comment: @AndrejBauer: numbers are known to be linearly ordered

Comment: The OP never mentioned numbers (except for cardinal numbers at the end), so at least I never guessed they were discussing numerical datatypes. Also, complex numbers are not linearly ordered, but that's not important.

Comment: @AndrejBauer: from the book: "Type conversions are either narrowing or widening. A narrowing conversion
converts a value to a type that cannot store even approximations of all of the 
values of the original type. For example, converting a double to a float in 
Java is a narrowing conversion, because the range of double is much larger 
than that of float. A widening conversion converts a value to a type that 
can include at least approximations of all of the values of the original type."

Comment: I don't think people are required to read books referred to to understand questions. The term *datatype* is much more general than *numeric datatype*, and that's how I understood it. In any case – whatever, it's not important, enjoy my upvote.

Comment: @AndrejBauer: the OP inserted the link on purpose. I think you also missed the reference to the datatype int., and the allusions to *approximation*.